# Передача переменных в методы

Tags: objective-c, утечка-памяти

Если пишу в Obj-C следующим образом:

```
@interface ClassB:NSObject
{
    ClassA* point;
}
-(void)setPoint(ClassA *)newPoint

//Реализация метода

-(void)setPoint(ClassA *)newPoint            
{
    point = newPoint;
}

//main
    ClassB* myClass = [[ClassB alloc]init]; 
    ClassA* myPoint = [[ClassA alloc]init]; 
    [myClass setPoint:myPoint];
```

Мне не понятно, каким образом передается переменная? В методе создается копия или нет? Или все переменные myPoint, newPoint и point в итоге будут одинаковыми указателями? Как грамотно очистить память после этого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

грамотно позволять системе делать грязную работу за вас, просто пишите **@property**. всегда. и везде.

`@property (strong) id object;` - сохранит сильную ссылку на указатель

`@property (copy) id object;` - скопирует себе объект и сохранит сильную ссылку на него, то есть будет послано сообщение **copy** к тому, что мы сетим

старое значение будет освобождено в обоих случаях, то есть чтобы удалить все, что там было сохранено, вызываем `self.object = nil`

ну а вашем случае будет просто записана ссылка на объект в instance variable вашего класса

Answer (score 1):

- У вас не верный `setter`. Например, увеличили счетчик ссылки на `point` присвоением самого себя и получили утечку памяти.

  ClassB* myClass = [[ClassB alloc]init];

  myClass.point = myClass.point;

Второй минус вашего сеттера - вы не сможете использовать [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)

- Как писал [@iFreeman](/users/16210/ifreeman) не используйте внутренние переменные класса `@property (strong) id object;` -решает все проблемы
- Если вы используете ARC, память чистить не надо, компилятор сам подсчитает за вас ссылки и расставить `release/retain`-ы в нужных местах.